# Does MySQL or MariaDB support double literals (double precision)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, datatypes, syntax, floating-point

MySQL seems to support [`double precision`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)

> The `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` types represent approximate numeric data values. MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.

Is there a method to declare that a literal is a `double precision` and **not** a `float`, `decimal` or anything else? I don't see this mentioned in the docs on [*Numeric Literals*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html). In PostgreSQL, I could coerce a literal to a `double precision` with

```
SELECT 1::double precision,
  double precision '1',
  CAST(1 AS double precision);
```

Answer (score 1):

Though not in the docs explicitly on [*Numeric Literals*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html). You can make a `double precision` literal with scientific notation (using `e0`) which seems to work,

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT 1.0e0 AS "se_decimal", 1e0 AS "se_nodecimal", 1.0 AS "decimal";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> SHOW CREATE TABLE foo;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| foo   | CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `se_decimal` double NOT NULL,
  `se_nodecimal` double NOT NULL,
  `decimal` decimal(2,1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is actually supported by the SQL Spec, which shifts the literal from `<exact numeric literal>` to `<approximate numeric literal>` when it sees the `e` or `E`. From SQL 2011n spec,

```
<approximate numeric literal> ::=
  <mantissa> E <exponent>
```

This is what the docs on [*Numeric Literals*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html) presumably refer to when it says,

> **Approximate-value numeric literals** are represented in scientific notation with a mantissa and exponent. Either or both parts may be signed. Examples: `1.2E3`, `1.2E-3`, `-1.2E3`, `-1.2E-3`.

Though the docs don't say the type, it's `double` (see above).

See also,

- [How does the SQL Spec specify literals with a decimal should be handled?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/209361/2639)